# How to output only relevant changes while scraping for new discounts?

Tags: python

In a previous question I got the answer from Hedgehog! ([How to check for new discounts and send to telegram if changes detected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314322/python-scrape-issue-with-class-on-a-website/))

But another question is, how can I get only the new (products) items in the output and not all the text what is changed. My feeling is that the output I got is literally anything what is changed on the website and not only the new added discount.

Here is the code, and see the attachment what the output is. Thanks again for all the effort.

```
`# Import all necessary packages
import requests, time, difflib, os, re, schedule, cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

# Define scraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

# Send a message via a telegram bot
def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
bot_token = '1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXG5pses8'
bot_chatID = '-XXXXXXXXXXX'
send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID     
+ '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

response = requests.get(send_text)

return response.json()

PrevVersion = ""
FirstRun = True
while True:

# Download the page with the specified URL
response = scraper.get("https://").content

# Url for in the messages to show
url = "https://"

# Act like a browser
#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36         (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

# Parse the downloaded page and check for discount on the page
soup =  BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
def get_discounts(soup):
    for d in soup.select('.cept-discount'):
        if d.text != '' and 65 < int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, d.text))) < 99:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
# Remove all scripts and styles
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()
discounts = get_discounts(soup)

soup = soup.get_text()

# Compare the page text to the previous version and check if there are any discounts in your range
if PrevVersion != soup and discounts:       
    # On the first run - just memorize the page
    if FirstRun == True:
        PrevVersion = soup
        FirstRun = False
        print ("Start Monitoring "+url+ ""+ str(datetime.now()))
    else:
        print ("Changes detected at: "+ str(datetime.now()))
        OldPage = PrevVersion.splitlines()
        NewPage = soup.splitlines()
        diff = difflib.context_diff(OldPage,NewPage,n=0)
        out_text = "\n".join([ll.rstrip() for ll in '\n'.join(diff).splitlines() if     ll.strip()])
        print (out_text)
        OldPage = NewPage

        # Send a message with the telegram bot
        telegram_bot_sendtext("Nieuwe prijsfout op Pepper " + url )

       # print ('\n'.join(diff))
        PrevVersion = soup
else:
    print( "No Changes "+ str(datetime.now()))

time.sleep(5)
continue`
```

Comment: Attachment is missing, could you add it, to get a closer look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

As discussed, your assumptions are going in the right direction, all the changes identified by the `difflib` will be displayed.

It may be possible to adjust the content of `difflib` but I am sure that `difflib` is not absolutely necessary for this task.

#### How to fix?

First step is to upgrade `get_discounts(soup)` to not only check if discount is in range but also get information of the item itself, if you like to display or operate on later:

```
def get_discounts(soup):
        discounts = []
        for d in soup.select('.cept-discount'):
            if d.text != '' and 65 < int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, d.text))) < 99:
                discounts.append({
                    'name':d.find_previous('strong').a.get('title'),
                    'url':d.find_previous('strong').a.get('href'),
                    'discount':d.text,
                    'price':d.parent.parent.select_one('.thread-price').text,
                    'bestprice':d.previous_sibling.text
                })
        return discounts
```

Second step is to check if there is a new discount, close to the `difflib` but more focused:

```
def compare_discounts(d1: list, d2: list):

    diff = [i for i in d1 + d2 if i not in d1]
    result = len(diff) == 0
    if not result:
        return diff
```

Last step is to react to changes from the discounts, if so it will print the urls from so you can go directly to the offert products.

**Note** *Cause we have stored additional information in our list of dicts you can adjust the printing to get also the whole information or specific attributes*

```
if newDiscounts:
    #Send a message with the telegram bot
    print('\n'.join([c['url'] for c in newDiscounts]))
    telegram_bot_sendtext("Nieuwe prijsfout op Pepper " + url)
```

#### Example

```
import requests, time, difflib, os, re, schedule, cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

# Define scraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

# Send a message via a telegram bot
def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token = '1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXG5pses8'
    bot_chatID = '-XXXXXXXXXXX'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()

PrevVersion = ""
PrevDiscounts = []
FirstRun = True

def get_discounts(soup):
        discounts = []
        for d in soup.select('.cept-discount'):
            if d.text != '' and 65 < int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, d.text))) < 99:
                discounts.append({
                    'name':d.find_previous('strong').a.get('title'),
                    'url':d.find_previous('strong').a.get('href'),
                    'discount':d.text,
                    'price':d.parent.parent.select_one('.thread-price').text,
                    'bestprice':d.previous_sibling.text
                })
        return discounts


def compare_discounts(d1: list, d2: list):

    diff = [i for i in d1 + d2 if i not in d1]
    result = len(diff) == 0
    if not result:
        return diff
    

while True:

    # Download the page with the specified URL
    response = requests.get("https://nl.pepper.com/nieuw").content

    # Url for in the messages to show
    url = "https://nl.pepper.com/nieuw"

    # Parse the downloaded page and check for discount on the page
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

    # Remove all scripts and styles
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()

    discounts = get_discounts(soup)

    souptext = soup.get_text()

    # Compare the page text to the previous version and check if there are any discounts in your range
    if PrevVersion != souptext and discounts:       
        # On the first run - just memorize the page
        if FirstRun == True:
            PrevVersion = souptext
            PrevDiscounts = discounts
            FirstRun = False
            print ("Start Monitoring "+url+ ""+ str(datetime.now()))
        else:
            print ("Changes detected at: "+ str(datetime.now()))
            newDiscounts = compare_discounts(PrevDiscounts,discounts)
            if newDiscounts:
                
                print('\n'.join([c['url'] for c in newDiscounts]))
                #Send a message with the telegram bot
                telegram_bot_sendtext("Nieuwe prijsfout op Pepper " + url)
            else:
                print('These are general changes but there are no new discounts available.')
            PrevVersion = souptext
            PrevDiscounts = discounts
    else:
        print( "No Changes "+ str(datetime.now()))

    time.sleep(10)
    continue
```

#### Output

```
Start Monitoring https://nl.pepper.com/nieuw 2021-12-12 12:28:38.391028
No Changes 2021-12-12 12:28:54.009881
Changes detected at: 2021-12-12 12:29:04.429961
https://nl.pepper.com/aanbiedingen/gigaset-plug-startpakket-221003
No Changes 2021-12-12 12:29:14.698933
No Changes 2021-12-12 12:29:24.985394
No Changes 2021-12-12 12:29:35.271794
No Changes 2021-12-12 12:29:45.629790
No Changes 2021-12-12 12:29:55.917246
Changes detected at: 2021-12-12 12:30:06.184814
These are general changes but there are no new discounts available.
```

Comment: O man this is exactly what i needed! You are my hero and the best python programmer of stackoverflow :)

The only message i got is 

  File "pepperbotdiscount.py", line 74
    if (changes := compare_discounts(PrevDiscounts,discounts)) != None:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is this easy to fix? I'm using python3 on my linux machine.

Comment: Thank for the flowers, but I am not :) - Anyway changed the walrus operator assignment and the unnecessary check. Lets try the fixed example.